# Force 'aps-environment' entitlement to 'development' even for distribution builds

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile

My `APS Environment` is set to `development` in my *app.entitlements* file.

However when I build my application as an archive (to generate an .ipa file), the aps-environment entitlement is automatically changed to `production` because it uses a Distribution provisioning.
I read in [APS Environment Entitlement](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/aps-environment) Apple documentation that [these default behaviour can be changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afCra.png).

But I didn't find a way to do it. Is it possible to change (force) this aps-environment to `development` even for a dirstribution build ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I think, what meant of "Default settings can be modified" is only works on your local environment, when it published to appstoreconnect it'll automatic use production.